# Wordpress Custom Main Page

Tags: wordpress

Already costomised my theme's main page from Reading option in Settings tab(on Dashboard) and now how to display all posts under Blog link on it(ie, how to show all posts under blog).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In reading options set blog to be the posts page.
[image]

Here you can set front page, and posts page. Both need to be static pages that you have created in Pages admin panel. Blog is just another page that you have specified in reading settings to show posts.